# How to pause VBA execution until the called UDF finishes its execution?

Tags: vba, execution

I have a macro that is calling a UDF that subsequently refresh some data on my workbook and then I call some other macro to perform some operation on refreshed data. The problem is the VBA execution continues before the refresh data completes. I want to hold execution until the UDF completes its job. the code is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Application.Run ("RefreshSnowflake()")    
End Sub
```

An example of what I've tried:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Application.Run ("RefreshSnowflake()")
    Do        
    Loop Until Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone
    MsgBox "Test."
End Sub
```

The problem is the messagebox is immidiately shown, meaning does not wait for RefreshSnowflake() UDF call to complete execution.
How can I achieve that?
I don't want to use Wait or Sleep with a certain time amount, I want the execution to be postpone for the exact amount that the UDF RefreshSnowflake() takes to complete its operation.
Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using `Application.Run` instead of just calling the routine like normal?

Comment: because I have AddinModule and XllModule connected, RefreshSnowflake is a UDF in the AddinModlue(C# code), so I have to call it this way.

Comment: Perhaps the Worksheet.Calculate event handling will work, that occurs after the worksheet is recalculated (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even))?

Answer (score 0):

With the code provided, would you would want to loop until the calculation state is done? (i.e. remove the "NOT")

```
Loop Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
```

Although I think a better way may be:

```
While Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
    DoEvents
Loop
```

That way, the code just waits rather than infinitely looping on nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this 
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Application.Run ("RefreshSnowflake()")
    Do
        DoEvents

    Loop Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone

    MsgBox "Tnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnest."

End Sub

the messagebox never showed up, I assume it got stuck in the loop.

Comment: If just checks it once, so it wouldn't be helpful

Comment: DoEvents waits for the spreadsheet to reach a ready state. Did you try the "better way" I proposed?

Comment: You could also include a Debug.Print `Application.CalculationState` line in the loop if you insist on the loop, then you can at least see the evaluated enum.

Comment: Also, are you aware that you can set watches, and step through your code with F8?

Comment: Andrew Wynn yes I tried the better way you suggested msgbox appeared immidiately meaning did not wait for UDF to complete, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: this is my latest attempt:Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.Run ("RefreshSnowflake()")
    If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
        DoEvents
    End If
    MsgBox "Tnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnest."
End Sub